# How to specify a default .editorconfig file that should be created in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I am using "EditorConfig for VS Code" extension which provides right-click option to create .editorconfig file in the current project directory. When created, a .editorconfig file has this content:

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
insert_final_newline = false
```

This is not matching my preferences so I need to change these config settings every time I start a new project which is tiresome because I am often creating a new projects when learning or to testing some javascript libs or framewokrs.

So is there a way to specify a default content of this file when created via this extension?

Answer (score 2):

If this is for your own use and not for project use, you can simply put that file in your home directory, so that every project not using EditorConfig will have it effective.

Answer (score 0):

For set your default template of "editorconfig":

1. Go to Vscode settings
2. In search form input `@ext:EditorConfig.EditorConfig`
3. Uncheck `Generate Auto`
4. In field `Template` input path for your own editorconfig template